# Can we change one rotation mode of a disk continuously into one of the other two, keeping the angular momentum vector constant?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotation, moment-of-inertia

If we consider a disk (with a uniform mass density), we have one mode of rotation around the axis perpendicular to the disk and two modes of rotation around two axes, perpendicular to each other, as well as to the axis perpendicular to the disk. The moments of inertia of the disk rotating in the last two modes are equal and bigger than the moment of inertia of the disk rotating in the first mode.

Now if we have a disk rotating in the first mode, can we (let's assume we're in free space, for simplicity) change the rotation continuously into one of the other two modes by subjecting the disk to torques, and at the same time keeping the angular momentum vector constant?

Answer (score 0):

By playing with a dinner plate I saw that this is, of course, possible. While applying two opposite torques on opposite sides of the plates to stop the first rotation and at the same time applying two couples of torques on opposite sides of the disk (each of these couples rotated 90 degrees with respect to each other), in such a way that at every time the angular momentum stays the same, we can continuously change the rotating disk in the first mode change in one of the two other (equal) rotation modes of the disk. The angular velocity of the final rotation mode is less than that of the first rotation mode due to the increased moment of inertia.